# "message": "Undefined property: Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::$token"

Tags: php, laravel

I keep getting this error when trying to verify the hashed token with the unhashed token.

> "message" : "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$token"

Can someone please help me since I've been stuck on this error for nearly 2 hours now.

```
public function verifyResetPageAccess(Request $request){
    $email = $request->email; 
    $token = $request->token;

    // $exists = password_reset::where('email', $email)->first();
    $exists = DB::table('password_resets')->where('email',$email);
    $dbToken = $exists->select('token');

    if($exists === null){
        return response(['message'=>'unauthorized'],401);       
    }else{
        if(Hash::check($token, $dbToken->token))  {
            return response(['message'=>'authorized']);
        }else{
            return response(['message'=>'error occured'],401);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are trying to access `$exists` even when is `null` in the line: `$dbs Token = $exists->select('token');`. move this line to inside the `else`. and try again. if the error percists your `$dbToken` doesn't have a `token` in any scenario.

Comment: I tried that same issue

Comment: check the content of `$dbToken`

Comment: What im doing is taking the plain text token from the request then trying to compare it to the hashed token in the database. The email is correct so I dont understand why this is not working.

Comment: the error says that you are trying to access an undefined property `token`. so probably the error is in : `$dbToken->token`

Comment: that why you need to check what is inside `$dbToken`

Comment: When I do that I get maximum response size reached error inside postman

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227714/discussion-between-andre-walker-and-lizardcoder).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you are trying to get a field value directly on a Builder. you should use get() or first() to run the query and get the result before trying to get field value. You can change this line to get the result:

```
$dbToken = $exists->select('token');
```

it should become

```
$dbToken = $exists->select('token')->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it I had to use pluck on the query builder and fix the request body and now it works

Comment: It's totally legit to answer your own question but without a solution (code) this is not a real answer.